# Why is If statement is showing error in following OCaml program?

Tags: ocaml

I am new to `OCaml`, please help me understand the reason of the following error.

```
let rec union l1 l2= match l2 with
 []->l1
 |x::xs->if not(List.mem x l1) then l1@[x];union l1 xs ;;

Characters 80-86:
   |x::xs->if not(List.mem x l1) then l1@[x];union l1 xs;;
                                      ^^^^^^
```

> Error: This expression has type 'a list
>              but an expression was expected of type unit

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Abhishek! Please explain what you would like to happen, not only what is going wrong. See how to write a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm you would like to implement is:

when `l2` is empty, return `l1`, else when `l2 = x::xs` then:

- add `x` at the end of `l1` if it is not there already
- call the procedure recursively with `l2 = xs` and the new `l1`.

This is not what your implementation achieves.

Your implementation does the following:
create the list `l1@[x]`, do nothing with it. Then make the recursive call.

To use the value `l1@[x]`, you need the bind it to some name, for instance:

```
let rec union l1 l2= 
  match l2 with 
  []->l1 
 | x::xs->
   if not(List.mem x l1) 
   then let newl1 = l1@[x] in union newl1 xs
   else union l1 xs
```

Here I also completed the necessary `else` branch with some meaningful statement.

You don't even need to find a name, you can directly write the equivalent:

```
let rec union l1 l2= 
  match l2 with 
  []->l1 
 | x::xs->
   union (if not(List.mem x l1) then l1@[x] else l1) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

An `if` without an `else` needs to have type `unit`, but yours has type `'a list`. Think of it this way: if your condition is false, what do you expect your function to return?

PS: `l1 @ [x]` is an expression without any side effects. Putting it as a statement as its own without doing anything with its result accomplishes nothing. You probably want to use `l1@[x]` as the first argument to `union` instead of just `l1`.